# codename one actionlistener is not calling properly in ipad device

Tags: actionlistener, textfield, codenameone

i want to update the text field value when i was changed.for this i use action listener because every updation time one trigger was fired in my code so,that's the reason i used action listener instead of data changed listener.for data changed listener on key pressed the listener is called updation done but my requirement is after completion of entering the data on text field only the listener is called.but it is not calling properly.

please find the below code,

```
 agencyWorker.addActionListener(createAgencyActionListener(agencyWorker,eventPostchedules.getSerialId()));

 private ActionListener createAgencyActionListener(final TextField      searchField, String serialId){

   return new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        String agencyText = searchField.getText();
        searchField.setPreferredW(110);

        roasterDao = RoasterDao.getInstance();
        roasterDao.updateEventPostScheduleAgency(agencyText, serialId, "supervisor");
        }

    }; 
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this on my iPad and action listener was invoked as expected. Check that you don't have a different error that is causing this e.g. networking error related to [https change in iOS](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html).

FYI on a side note, it's **really** bad to write this:

```
searchField.setPreferredW(110);
```

You are limiting the size of the field based in pixels which is rarely the right thing to do. The method is deprecated for a reason...

Comment: TextField is growing means changes its size when we type more text, without using of this "searchField.setPreferredW(110)", how we can control this growing nature of this component. Could you please help me on this.

Comment: You can set the columns of the text field which effectively determine it's preferred size but use character width instead of pixels. You can size elements with layout managers, you can place the text field in a layout manager with the proper constraint to match your requirements. E.g. TableLayout has a width constraint that works with percentages.